# Jupyter notebook automatic import of module when starting Python kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working in a Jupyter directory that contains different notebooks, in different languages. When I open a Python notebook, I would like the Python kernel to automatically import a specific module, if found in the same folder.

For example, let say I have the file tree below:

```
root_folder
  |- subfolder_1
  |    |- script1.ipynb
  |    |- script2.ipynb
  |    `- startup.py
  `- subfolder_2
       `- script3.ipynb
```

I would like the Python kernel to automatically import the `startup.py` module on `script1.ipynb` or `script2.ipynb` opening. For `script3.ipynb`, I would like not to raise any error (but try and import a `startup.py` in case it exists).

The goal is to provide some folder specific functions *without having to manually import this module*.

I know it is not "expensive" to write `from startup import *`, but I would like to do without it.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize startup files.

You should be able to find them in `<profile>/startup` directory.

Copied from [docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/overview.html#startup-files):

> If you want some code to be run at the beginning of every IPython
>   session with a particular profile, the easiest way is to add Python
>   (.py) or IPython (.ipy) scripts to your /startup directory.
>   Files in this directory will always be executed as soon as the IPython
>   shell is constructed, and before any other code or scripts you have
>   specified. If you have multiple files in the startup directory, they
>   will be run in lexicographical order, so you can control the ordering
>   by adding a ‘00-‘ prefix.

Comment: I tried that. There are two issues: 1- the startup file is global (no way to have one file per `subfolder_*`), and 2- I did not succeeded in using the variables of the startup file in the notebook.